# How to encrypt file GPG

Tags: python, gnupg

How to encrypt file GPG

I have a public key that has the following format

```
9903 2e04 655d 362b 1108 00a5 dbe1 82fe
44f0 eed7 7085 b773 cffe c414 cb4f de57
d09d e940 f28b dee2 e629 3e21 76ec 5201
9bcf e04a de84 da2b 7ec7 ef48 3a2b 2287
fdff 5a68 b473 6886 a5e8 f3a9 1fab 5d0c
da06 b407 24da ec3f 23ce 2b59 012d a08d
6219 12e4 ac9a dfc0 5b4b e33c cd4d 280b
a5e8 5ef6 4d2a 733f e73a 0174 2c58 a079
d714 36e1 6672 4c50 c5b6 6a1f 01e4 ab6c
aacb a804 c992 e6e6 083a e698 3d29 2881
003e fae5 a7ae 1ef7 ab9f ab7c 22c9 2b01
d849 2554 e12d 3f36 74c5 7c41 b5af 2b7d
```

I don't know what to do since I was expecting the normal GPG format.

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----

mQMuBGVdNisRCACl2+GC/kTw7tdwhbdzz/7EFMtP3lfQnelA8ove4uYpPiF27FIB
m8/gSt6E2it+x+9IOisih/3/Wmi0c2iGpejzqR+rXQzaBrQHJNrsPyPOK1kBLaCN
Yh.....
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

The problem is that I need to use that public key to encrypt information with the same format as the public key, using python-gnupg.

I have tried encrypting using armor:

```
gpg --recipient "key_name" --output encrypted_file.gpg --encrypt file_to_encrypt.txt
```

Trying to convert it to hexadecimal:

```
gpg --recipient "key_name" --encrypt --armor --yes file_to_encrypt.txt | xxd -p
```

And it gives:

----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----

hQIOAw4cZD6gIf1jEAgAuUTlvmYGPhVfvVXeUuMD9JG9B4TlX62XUaoktkRbIQ73
BS28XDoEDq7xsJtG8+heZeGdqTWix84MzJMizrmcuOk+taDkNjVQFKGTV/V7Gxdt.....
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----

I don't know what I'm doing wrong

It must be like this since the process already exists, and I'm migrating it to Python. In NiFi, it does it in a way that I can't quite understand.